# MonoDevelop: html reformatting?

Tags: monodevelop

i'm using Monodevelop under Linux to write an Asp.NET app. 
In Visual Studio there's a nice key shortcuts to reformat the html code (with right indentation etc.). Also in monodevelop there's a function "Reformat" but it doesn't affect the Html. It's my fault ? Where am i wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no formatting support for HTML yet. Only for C# and XML.

Comment: 3.0.2 as lot's of improvements but none for the html/javascript side.